# Geom_errorbar position does not work

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, errorbar

My problem is with ggplot's geom_bar and geom_errorbar. I set both of their position to position_dodge() and I expect the geom_errorbar's position to be inherited from geom_bar but nothing happens.
My dataframe looks like this:

```
    year <- c(rep(c('1998', '2008', '2018'),2)) 
JZ <- c(3.04, 3.4, 3.08, 2.81, 2.93, 2.83)
 SD <- c(0.79, 0.98, 1.05, 1.1, 1.47, 1.57) 
type <- c(rep('JZa', 3), rep('JZm', 3))
 mydata <- data.frame(year, JZ, SD)
```

My code looks like this:

```
 ggplot(mydata, aes(x=year, y=JZ, ymin=JZ-SD, ymax=JZ+SD))+
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = type), position = position_dodge(), width=6)+
 scale_fill_grey() + theme_bw() + 
 labs(title="", x='', y="Mean number of nestlings \u00B1 SD")  +
 geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(), width=1.5) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1998, 2018, 10))
```

.. and I get a plot like this: 
[image]

I've tried many different things.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to supply a value to the `width` parameter within `position_dodge`.

Comment: @Salman 
    year <- c(rep(c('1998', '2008', '2018'),2))
    JZ <- c(3.04, 3.4, 3.08, 2.81, 2.93, 2.83)
    SD <- c(0.79, 0.98, 1.05, 1.1, 1.47, 1.57)
    type <- c(rep('JZa', 3), rep('JZm', 3))
    mydata <- data.frame(year, JZ, SD)

Comment: @Roland 
I've tried that already, didn't work.

Comment: can you add a sample of output @karolanna

Comment: put the `fill = type` into the `aes` on the first line

Comment: Thanks @RichardTelford, it worked!